# AWS Elasticbeanstalk with Django: Incorrect application version found on all instances

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a django application on elasticbeanstalk.  It has been working fine then suddenly stopped and I cannot figure out why.

When I do `eb deploy` I get

```
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.      

Alert: An update to the EB CLI is available. Run "pip install --upgrade awsebcli" to get the latest version.
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
INFO: Running ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/web-cdi_011017.pem ec2-user@54.188.214.227 if ! grep -q 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}' /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf ; then echo -e 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}' | sudo tee -a /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf; fi;
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
INFO: Running ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/web-cdi_011017.pem ec2-user@54.188.214.227 sudo /etc/init.d/httpd reload
Reloading httpd: [  OK  ]
```

When I then run `eb health`, I get

> Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version
>   "app-c56a-190604_135423" (deployment 300).

If I `eb ssh` and look in `/opt/python/current` there is nothing there so nothing is being copied across

I think something may be wrong with `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`.  Somehow the directory was deleted and setup again.  This is the `config.yml`

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: app-prod
  scoring-dev:
    environment: app-dev
environment-defaults:
  app-prod:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: my-app
  default_ec2_keyname: am-app_011017
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2::platform/Python 2.7 running
    on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.3.1
  default_region: us-west-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

Please, any ideas about how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I run into this every now and then on elastic beanstalk for no discernible reason.  Sometimes I have to deploy 3 or 4 times before it goes successfully.  But I would also tail the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` while you are deploying and make sure no other errors are happening.

Comment: @littleforest how do you tail the log while deploying?

Comment: You need to ssh into the box before you start the deploy. Then just run: `tail -f /var/log/eb-activity.log`. Watch the log while it deploys. If there are no errors then just try the deploy a couple of times. Eventually it should work. If you have autoscaling set up, then you can also just terminate the instance and have it boot up a new one. Then try the deploy again. Sometimes that helps.

Comment: I tried that and nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest AWS stack for python 2.7 and that sorted it

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and the cause the command timeout

**Default max deployment time -Command timeout- is 600 (10 minutes)**

Your Environment →  Configuration → Deployment preferences → Command timeout

Increase the Deployment preferences for example 1800

or upgrade the instance type to work faster